# How to fix incorrect timestamp calculations? [OpenRtspClient]

Tags: timestamp, h.264, rtsp, live555, rtcp

My `RTSP Source`'s  `RTCP` `SR` are not reliable for some of the calculated timestamps of `H.264` streams frequently resulting in large negative jumps.

Here is an example from the debug log. See how it jumps from 101006.6130 to -4193861.6830 and continues that way.

```
101619 : 5cd3c38 Sample 63682 bytes time 100605.6130 to 100605.6131 latency 1264447034.4738
101715 : 5cd3c38 Sample 74194 bytes time 100706.6130 to 100706.6131 latency 1264447039.4738
101815 : 5cd3c38 Sample 72484 bytes time 100804.6130 to 100804.6131 latency 1264447038.4738
101923 : 5cd3c38 Sample 95679 bytes time 100906.6130 to 100906.6131 latency 1264447031.4738
102023 : 5cd3c38 Sample 93004 bytes time 101006.6130 to 101006.6131 latency 1264447031.4738
102134 : 5cd3c38 Sample 91388 bytes time -4193861.6830 to -4193861.6829 latency 1260152052.1778
102222 : 5cd3c38 Sample 90912 bytes time -4193738.1730 to -4193738.1729 latency 1260152088.6878
102328 : 5cd3c38 Sample 105902 bytes time -4193636.1730 to -4193636.1729 latency 1260152083.6878
102430 : 5cd3c38 Sample 106334 bytes time -4193537.1730 to -4193537.1729 latency 1260152081.6878
102520 : 5cd3c38 Sample 107120 bytes time -4193437.1730 to -4193437.1729 latency 1260152090.6878
```

So, my question is:

> How can I solve this problem using `Live555` media lib? Should I
>   ignore `RTCP` info or what is the recommended solution and how can I
>   apply in `Live555`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using live555 exclusively on client? With *unmodified* source code? Where does the logging info in your question come from?

Generally, there will *always* be one jump in timestamp fairly close to the beginning of the stream: this occurs when the first RTCP SR is received by the client at which point the client *resets* the timestamp. This is necessary so that a client can synchronize multiple streams as RTP timestamps in both audio and video each begin with a randomized offset. The RTCP SR contains the mapping from RTP to NTP timestamp, which allows the client to synchronize the timestamps. The fact that the timestamp jumps negative shouldn't matter since both RTP and NTP timestamps are unsigned.

Live555 takes care of this synchronization and this is why you might see a jump in timestamp fairly close to the beginning. You have the option of either ignoring all samples received prior to RTCP synchronisation or you can perform a more complex offset mapping to zero both prior RTCP synchronisation and after. You can check whether synchronization has occurred by calling the live555 `RtpSource::hasBeenSynchronizedUsingRTCP()` method.

If however you are seeing multiple jumps, then you may have a different problem. In that case, please edit your question by adding more detail, such as RTSP server used, RTSP client, etc.

Comment: I modified Live555 Open Rtsp code...make it more object oriented and usable in multithread enviromented...The problem is thats some of[not all] my rtsp Servers [ which are IP Cameras] even does not take-send any  RTCP info...So RtpSource::hasBeenSynchronizedUsingRTCP() never be true...

Comment: By the way, when i connect my rtsp source to decoder and render it everthing is OK since i do not give any time stamp values to media samples...But when try to record i have to give timestamps then record file contains all frames but with wrong time stamps...

Comment: More explanation i s at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558448/wrong-presentation-time-at-h264-streams-live555-openrtspclient

Comment: I do not think this is because of RtpSource::hasBeenSynchronizedUsingRTCP() flag...I record frames  at time intervals such as 10 minutes..Suppose that first 5 ten-minute record are correct but later ones becomes wrong...It should be syncronized already after 50 minute...

Comment: Ok, so what you are saying is that the jumps do not occur on RTCP sync since some of your IP camera's don't even send RTCP reports? I would suggest tackling one RTSP server type at a time to determine the best working solution. This is however not a live555 problem: in my experience live555 implements the RTP standard correctly. If the RTP timestamps sent by the camera jump for no particular reason and you can verify this (IMO this would be best using the unmodified openRTSP client to ensure that you didn't introduce any bugs) I would take this up with the manufacturer of the camera.

Comment: Well, i used the original OpenRtspClient...Get also unstable results... It is hard to produce error again and again...It work for 1 hour than it gets wrong values or at the start it gets wrong values then it is corrected...The problem is that it effects my recording...

Comment: And we write manufacturer they test it send us those orinal time stamps values, there seem to be nothing wrong with them...May be we modified muxer in a wron way...

Comment: Are you recording a single stream to file or do you need to sync it with audio or other video: as an alternative you could try just generating timestamps (which shouldn't be a problem for single streams) i.e. in DS increase the value of the timestamp by 10 000 000/frame rate for each frame: for H.264 you might need to account for decoding order vs presentation order as well as the different frame types (I, P, B) but you would have to research that.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know the implementation of RTCP SR; consequently i don't know the units which `100605.xxxx`  represents. However, if i assume that generally if i believe that they are derived from PTS/DTS values of the stream's 90 kHz clock value.

If this is true, it is well known that such a clock timers recycles themselves at 2^33 bits. This is called as WRAPAROUND of the clock. If this is printed as a signed number - this will become positive. Such a wraparound will happen exactly after a certain value of Clock.

To validate that indeed the highest and lowest values will always be in same or similar range.

The other such possibility is called *discontinuity* which arise when the source timebase suddenly shifts (possibly due to some fault).